# Application Loader client version does not meet required version

Tags: ios, air, app-store-connect, application-loader

i'm uploading some ipa files with Application Loader, and i have the error :

```
Apple's web service operation was not successful 
Unable to authenticate the package: 697761522.itmsp 
Client version 1.5.2.2 does not meet minimum required version 1.6.4 (1046)
```

I never had this pb before, uploaded several ipa's without worries.
The only thing changing in my ipa's are the use of game center.

thanks !

Comment: xcode version that you are using?

Comment: I made my app with Adobe Flash (AIR), without xcode. I downloaded the last application loader version, but the osx is 10.6.8 and it wants 10.7. Maybe it comes from that..

Comment: Use version 2.9 which is the latest version of Application Loader.

Comment: i hate apple more and more each day, so complicated to work with them. Thanks by the way.

Comment: If you use their tool (developing native apps) it is very easy because all these are built in xcode. You just chose the hard way ;-)

Comment: I work on Windows, i use a friend's mac to upload. I'll ask him to upgrade his osx version. Flash allows you to export on ios & android directly, for me it's the easiest way :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by downloading Application Loader greater than 1.6.4.

Here is the download link: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg

Install it. After installing, run the application loader, login to itunes connect and that's it, you can upload now your updates.